# Input tensors to a Model must come from `tf.layers.Input` when I concatenate two models with Keras API on Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm creating a wide and deep model using Keras functional API on tensorflow.

When I try to merge the two models, the below error occurred.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 merged_out = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([wide_model.output, deep_model.output])
>         2 merged_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(merged_out)
>   ----> 3 combined_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=wide_model.input + [deep_model.input], outputs=merged_out)
>         4 print(combined_model.summary())
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in **init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       111 
>       112   def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
>   --> 113     super(Model, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>       114     # Create a cache for iterator get_next op.
>       115     self._iterator_get_next = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py
>   in **init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>        77         'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
>        78       # Graph network
>   ---> 79       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
>        80     else:
>        81       # Subclassed network
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py
>   in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       362     self._setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>       363     try:
>   --> 364       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       365     finally:
>       366       self._setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py
>   in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name)
>       193                          'must come from `tf.layers.Input`. '
>       194                          'Received: ' + str(x) +
>   --> 195                          ' (missing previous layer metadata).')
>       196       # Check that x is an input tensor.
>       197       # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `tf.layers.Input`.
>   Received: Tensor("add_1:0", shape=(1, ?, 163), dtype=float32) (missing
>   previous layer metadata).

Here is the code for concatenating the two.

```
merged_out = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([wide_model.output, deep_model.output])
merged_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(merged_out)
combined_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=wide_model.input + [deep_model.input], outputs=merged_out)
print(combined_model.summary())
```

For each model's inputs, I tried using `tf.layers.Input`with

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,X_resampled.shape[1]))
deep_inputs = tf.keras.Input(tensor=(inputs))
```

to make them `tf.layers.Input` as [this page](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/issues/87) mentions. 
But I'm still facing the same issue.

I'm using tensorflow==1.10.0

Could someone help me solving this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `inputs=wide_model.input + [deep_model.input]`, `wide.model.input` is probably not a list, so that you are passing a new `Add` tensor instead of a list of inputs. Try passing `inputs=[wide_model.input] + [deep_model.input]` instead